# Edit data from a form - Django

Tags: django, forms, model, django-forms, django-views

I'm looking for help on a very basic problem I know, but I can't get it fixed and I don't know where I did something wrong (as usual)

So basically I have created a model form "formulaire_equipement"

```
class formulaire_equipement(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Formulaire
    fields = '__all__'
```

based on the model "Formulaire" :

```
class Formulaire(models.Model) :
nom_equipement = models.CharField(max_length=200)
constructeur = models.CharField(max_length=100)
choix_categorie = [
    ('Encodeur', 'Encodeur'),
    ('Modulateur', 'Modulateur'),
    ('Packager', 'Packager'),
    ('Playout', 'Playout')
  ]
categorie = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=choix_categorie)
reference = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
IP = models.CharField(max_length=15)
identifiant = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
mot_de_passe = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

From there, I can submit the form and I already created a view where I can access and display the data submitted by the user.

```
 <h3> Nom : {{Formulaire.nom_equipement}} </br>
Constructeur : {{Formulaire.constructeur}} </br>
Catégorie : {{Formulaire.categorie}} </br>
Référence : {{Formulaire.reference}} </br>
IP management : <a href="http://{{Formulaire.IP}}/"> {{Formulaire.IP}} </a> </br>
Identifiant de connexion : {{Formulaire.identifiant}} </br>
Mot de passe : {{Formulaire.mot_de_passe}} </br> </h3>
<a class="btn" method="POST" href="{% url 'modifier_equipement' pk=Formulaire.pk %}"> modifier équipement </a>
<a class="btn" href="{% url 'supprimer_equipement' pk=Formulaire.pk %}"> supprimer équipement </a>
</div>
```

The problem comes when I try to edit the form previously created, through the url

```
path('fiche/<int:pk>/edit/', views.edit_formulaire, name='modifier_equipement')
```

referring to the view "edit_formulaire" :

```
def edit_formulaire(request, pk):
this_form = Formulaire.objects.get(id=pk)
form = formulaire_equipement(request.POST or None, instance=this_form)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    context = {
    'Formulaire':form
    }
    return render(request, 'adress_hub/edit_formulaire.html', context)
```

Then from there i get the "The view search.views.edit_formulaire didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." error and I know that it's because the form is not valid for some reasons, so the "if" loop is not verified and then I fall down to the end of the view which doesn't return an HttpResponse object.

But I can't figure why the form is not valid, or what am I doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I edited this to be more helpfull.
Your view must resemble to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#the-view). I'd try this way:

```
def edit_formulaire(request, pk):
    this_form = Formulaire.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formulaire_equipement(request.POST or None, instance=this_form)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # Redirect the user after submitting the form, for example:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') 
    else:
        form = formulaire_equipement(instance=this_form)
    context = {'Formulaire':form}
    return render(request, 'adress_hub/edit_formulaire.html', context)
```

Anyway, is something is wrong with your post and you want to know why in an easy why try adding:

```
if form.is_valid():
    # your code
else:
    print(form.errors)
```

Let me know if this works!,

Comment: Thanks for your response, it doesn't seems to work, I mean I don't see any information...

Comment: What means you don't see any information? what are you expecting vs what are you seeing? is your template using {{Formulaire}} instead of {{form}}?

Comment: I mean that I don't see anything, it doesn't change the error I am getting and I don't see anything printed at all.

I tried to rewrite the code as you said and it seems that the request.method == 'POST' isn't verified because I go directly to the "else:" part

Comment: `<h1>Modifier l'équipement</h1>

    <form action="{% url 'formulaire' %}" method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Sauvegarder"/>
    </form>`

Comment: Thanks. Try changing {{form.as_p}} with {{Formulaire.as_p}}.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I tried this

```
def edit_formulaire(request, pk):
    this_form = Formulaire.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = formulaire_equipement(request.POST or None, instance=this_form)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        context = {
        'Formulaire':form
        }
        return render(request, 'adress_hub/edit_formulaire.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'adress_hub/formulaire.html', locals())
```

and now I access the form with the data ! but when I save the form it doesn't replace the form it just create a new entry.